# CSS overflow-y property - scrolling divs

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have this set up:

```
<div>
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the inner divs has this CSS:

```
float: left; 
margin-right: 40px;
width: 100px;
```

the outer divs have this:

```
overflow-x: scroll;
height: 275px;
width: 300px;
```

The divs contain  a list of input checkboxes.  I want them to keep sliding right and then a horizontal scrollbar show.  instead, the div's wrap.  So now they are vertical and I am scrolling vertically instead.  How can I make them keep going to the right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the items Inside the overflow Container `Display:inline-block` and add `white-space:nowrap;` to the scrolling Container.

Comment: Did you remove the floatings?

Answer (score 1):

Try floating the inner divs to the left too, or try setting their display to inline-block.

Option A:

```
float: left;
overflow-x: scroll;
height: 275px;
width: 300px;
```

Option B:

```
display: inline-block;
overflow-x: scroll;
height: 275px;
width: 300px;
```